# Hiding view in stack view in iOS 10

Tags: swift, ios10, ios11, uistackview

When I hide a `UIView` inside `UIStackview`, on iOS 11 it nicely removes the gap and brings the adjacent `UIViews` closer inside the `UIStackView`. However, on iOS 10 it will not move the adjacent views and just leave the gap for the hidden view. Is there a way to get around it without having to manually move the views.

Answer (score 18):

Have you added your own height constraint to the UIView? It will cause a conflict with the constraint `height = 0` generated by the UIStackView when the UIView is hidden on iOS 10. Just lower the Priority of UIView height constraint (e.g. 999) and the UI will update properly.

[image]